# MethodSorter Name_Ascending not running in order

Tags: junit, playframework, junit-runner

I know unit tests should be flexible enough to be run in different order. But I have situation where I would want my test cases to run in a specific order. In this scenario I am testing my controllers with fakeApplication and FakeRequest of playframework 2.3. Despite annotating my test class with FixMethodOrder as NAME_ASCENDING my tests run in random order.

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class JobTest {

    @Test
    public void _1_addJob() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void _2_editJob() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

See below the screenshots where the test orders are swapped with no change in code.
[image: Test order 1]
[image: Test order 2]

Comment: I would merge these two test cases into one.

Comment: there should be no reason to ask your tests to run in a specified order

Comment: Yes, even I do not see `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)` working as expected. In fact, I see that 2 different threads are invoking my ` test1` and `test2` test cases. I expected the test case execution to be in order and sequential , ie `test1` -> `test2`, and to be run by a single thread. JVM version - 1.8 , junit - 4.12

Answer (score 0):

Define the order at the sbt level like this:

```
testGrouping <<= definedTests in Test map { tests =>
  tests.map { test =>
    import Tests._
    new Group(
      name = test.name,
      tests = Seq(test),
      runPolicy = InProcess)
  }.sortWith(_.name < _.name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I see randomization in test order.